# How can I type from right to left with phpword

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I need to write in word document in right to left direction .. any help?

I've uploaded the file "phpword" from 
http://phpword.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PhpVersion you are referring to is outdated and not maintaned (since long time). If you download the currently maintained version from [PhpWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), you can define the rtl like this (from Sample_36_RTL.php that is included in the project samples folder):

$textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars('سلام این یک پاراگراف راست به چپ است', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), array('rtl' => true));

Comment: This is not correct. It just set the Text Align, Not the Text Direction.

Comment: You are correct that this isn't working on the current version (the situation might be the same with 5 year older version as well). To be more exact, in current version this doesn't seem to even change the text alignment; that is a different line in the sample 36 code that does that.